# insight using fql for facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I tried the below query

```
     SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=3232322 AND     
     metric='application_active_users' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-12-12') AND    
     period=period('day')
```

I've got read_insights permissions,object_id,i'm passing the page id.

This insights,i create as an facebook app ,to this i'm passing the app access token.

I get an empty array as output.Am,i missing some thing?

Comment: Without wanting to ask a silly question: you are an admin of the page, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is an authentication issue because it would return an error (authentication error)
This might be a known issue with end_time; check bug already reported to facebook.  I have posted a work around there too that works.
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/232510993491615?browse=search_4f08c675cce9d2265724293